# Deleting file contents and writing to the empty file

Tags: bash

I have a number of web application views written in blaze. In my terminal
my folders that hold the files look like this

```
~/track/app/client/templates$ ls
reports   shared     users
```

All those are folders. Inside each folder, i have the file `app.html` for instance(each folder has a unique html name).

I want to be able to delete file contents of any folder inside templates.I am able to delete contents using `truncate -s 0 app.html` but this works when i am inside a folder,like `users`.

How can i delete contents of `users` folder while inside my current directory which is templates without having to start from root with `~/track/app/client/templates/users`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path?

```
truncate -s 0 users/app.html
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear a file: 
try typing

```
cat> filename
```

then press CTRL + C   which clears the file

To write into a file:

type

```
cat> filename
Then you can write whatever you want to be in the file here. 
This will be written in the file.
```

Then press enter 
Press CTRL + C again

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/390167/how-to-clear-text-in-a-file

Comment: You don't need ctrlC. You can write cat >filename <<EOF. When you are done you type EOF and cat exits.